# Is there an equivalent to \uput in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels

I am trying to learn TikZ, having some experience with pstrick.  I would like to add some labels to my figures and am used to the convenience of the pstricks macro `\uput{label separation}[relative angle](point){label}`.  For example `\uput{8pt}[100](1,0){$A$}` will put the label $A$ at the point (1,0), but 8 points away in the standard 100-degree direction.  So is there something equivalent in TiKZ?  In particular I would like to:

- specify the distance or separation between the point and the label, and
- specify the angle accurately, instead of being bound to 0, 45, 90, 135, 180, etc...

Here's a small example.

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{standalone}

    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, fit}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,through,backgrounds}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.06\linewidth, y=0.06\linewidth]
      \coordinate [label=45:$A$] (A) at (6,6);
      \coordinate [label=135:$B$] (B) at (1,4);
      \coordinate [label=-45:$D$] (D) at (4,1);
      \coordinate [label=-120:$C$] (C) at (0,0);
      \draw [line width=0.8pt] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle;
      \path [draw, name path=A--C, line width=0.8pt] (A) -- (C);
      \path [draw, name path=B--D, line width=0.8pt] (B) -- (D);
      \path [name intersections={of=A--C and B--D, by=P}];
      %\draw (P) node[anchor=-100]{$P$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]
I would like to put a label at the point named P.  The line I commented out does the job just fine, but I find it counterintuitive since my label is a `node` and not a `label`.  Also, how do I adjust the separation between the label and the point?

**Edit:**  Per @cfr's answer below, I can achieve what I need by inserting the line of code

```
    \draw (P) node[shift={(80:12pt)}]{$P$};
```

So, to summarize: an equivalent to the **pstrick** macro `\uput{label separation}[relative angle](point/position){label}` would be `\draw (point/position) node[shift=(relative angle:label separation)]{label}` in **TikZ**.

Comment: see TikZ & PGF Manual, section 17.10 The Label and Pin Options, page 238

Comment: @Zarko: I was indeed reading that section, and maybe I'm being dense, but I can't seem to be able to apply those commands.  Partly, because I feel that if I use `node` then TikZ will draw something (a circle, a square, ...) there. I'm going to include a small example.

Comment: Labels you can ad to coordinates too. An example, what you like to achieve would be very helpful,

Comment: `every label/.style = {label distance = <length>, inner sep = <length>}` ? Labels are actually nodes.

Comment: Nodes have to have a shape, but they don't have to be drawn. All labels are nodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might find the `quotes` library convenient.

Here's one way of adding the label without using the quotes syntax. I wouldn't actually bother with `intersections` here but would just use the midpoint of the short diagonal.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.06\linewidth, y=0.06\linewidth, line width=.8pt]
  \coordinate [label=45:$A$] (A) at (6,6);
  \coordinate [label=135:$B$] (B) at (1,4);
  \coordinate [label=-45:$D$] (D) at (4,1);
  \coordinate [label=-120:$C$] (C) at (0,0);
  \draw  (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle (A) -- (C) (B) -- (D) node [midway, above] {$P$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Using the `quotes` library enables us to use a more concise syntax. Combined with the `edge` operation, we can then construct a similar diagram using the following line of code.

```
\draw (0,0) coordinate ["-120:$C'$"] (C') -- +(4,1) coordinate ["-45:$D'$"] (D') -- +(6,6) coordinate ["45:$A'$"] (A') edge (C') -- +(1,4) coordinate ["135:$B'$"] (B') edge ["$P'$" right, pos=.35]  (D') -- cycle;
```

[image: similar shapes - different syntax]

`"<specification>"` adds a label (in the case of a coordinate or node) or a node (in the case of an edge). `"<specification>"'` 'swaps' the location of the label or node if `auto` placement is being used. In the case of a label, `"<angle>:<text>"` can be used to place the label node at a precise angle. `right`, `above` etc. are redefined within the specification to refer to the various 'standard' angles you might choose. Standard styles are available to set up custom defaults for format and placement.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.06\linewidth, y=0.06\linewidth, line width=.8pt]
  \coordinate [label=45:$A$] (A) at (6,6);
  \coordinate [label=135:$B$] (B) at (1,4);
  \coordinate [label=-45:$D$] (D) at (4,1);
  \coordinate [label=-120:$C$] (C) at (0,0);
  \draw  (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle (A) -- (C) (B) -- (D) node [midway, above] {$P$};
  \begin{scope}[xshift=50mm]
    \draw (0,0) coordinate ["-120:$C'$"] (C') -- +(4,1) coordinate ["-45:$D'$"] (D') -- +(6,6) coordinate ["45:$A'$"] (A') edge (C') -- +(1,4) coordinate ["135:$B'$"] (B') edge ["$P'$" right, pos=.35]  (D') -- cycle;
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## EDIT

As I understand it, when placing a label or pin etc., Ti*k*Z tries to be rather more clever than you may wish. If you request a non-standard angle, it 'snaps' the `anchor` of the node to the nearest compass point e.g. `30`, `90`, `110` etc. So, to enforce the angle, you need to enforce the `anchor`.

For example,

```
... coordinate [label={[anchor=-5]-185:$C$}, label={[anchor=15]-165:$C$}, label={-135:$C$}, label={[anchor=60]-120:$C$}] (C) ...
```

produces

[image: multiple labels with non-standard anchoring]

To place the `P` label, I would just create a shifted `edge node`. For example,

```
... edge node [midway, shift=(80:12pt)] {$P$}  ...
```

produces

[image: shifted edge node]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.06\linewidth, y=0.06\linewidth, line width=.8pt]
  \draw (0,0) coordinate [label={[anchor=-5]-185:$C$}, label={[anchor=15]-165:$C$}, label={-135:$C$}, label={[anchor=60]-120:$C$}] (C) -- +(4,1) coordinate [label=-45:$D$] (D) -- +(6,6) coordinate [label=45:$A$] (A) edge (C) -- +(1,4) coordinate [label=135:$B$] (B) edge node [midway, shift=(80:12pt)] {$P$}  (D) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I'm not sure I can handle your `quote` usage yet. Got to check the documentation. However, I can still see in your code, that though we declare C at -120 degrees, TikZ keeps putting it at -135 degrees. I agree with you that I shouldn't bother with `intersection` here, but I want to learn to do intersections in general. In my particular example, I want to set the label P at 80 degrees and get the label farther from the intersection, say 12 pt.  How do I achieve that?

Comment: @Minh Please see edit above.

Comment: The `shift` did it.  Thanks, that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

See, if the following MWE can help you:

```
\documentclass[ tikz,
                border=3mm,
                12pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.06\linewidth, y=0.06\linewidth,
    every label/.style = {label distance=3pt, inner sep=1pt},
     every path/.style = {draw, line width=0.8pt}
                    ]
\coordinate [label=45:$A$] (A) at (6,6);
\coordinate [label=135:$B$] (B) at (1,4);
\coordinate [label=-45:$D$] (D) at (4,1);
\coordinate [label=-120:$C$] (C) at (0,0);
\path (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle;
\path [name path=A--C] (A) -- (C);
\path [name path=B--D] (B) -- (D);
\path [name intersections={of=A--C and B--D,by={[label=above:$P$]P}}];
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your MWE is what I had tried at first, but, as a beginner with TikZ, I didn't want to  use the labeling option as I constructed the intersection.  Also, I don't like being constrained to `above`, etc... I would like to be able set up a specific angle.   Notice how label $C$ is not at -120 degrees but at -135 degrees.  (Same if I put 95 degrees.)  Is that something that can be changed in TikZ?  I like `label distance = 3pt`.  How do you specify it for only one particular label?  E.g. all labels can be 3pt away, but what if I want one label to be 12 pt away?  Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: Well, all those details are described in mentioned in the TikZ manual :-). For local changes of `label distance` you can ad it to label as `\coordinate [label={[label distance = 0pt] 45:$A$}] ...` Instead  `above` ... you can use angles as is in your MWE but resolution of angles seems to be rounded to 5 degrees.

Comment: Still, `\path [name intersections={of=A--C and B--D, by={[label=80:$P$]P} }];` puts the label at **45 degrees** instead of **80 degrees**.  And I get an error if I do `\path [name  intersections={of=A--C and B--D, by={[label=80:$P$, label distance=12pt]P} }];`. Is my syntax wrong?

Comment: sory, my information in previous comment was wrong. `node distance` cannot be changed locally. Instead it you should use `yshift` and `xshift`. anyway, your syntax is wrong and also doesn't work in this case (can not be nested in already nested option). in this case try the following: `\path [name intersections={of=A--C and B--D,by={P}}];
\coordinate[label={[yshift=12pt]85:$P$}] (p) at (P);` Maybe here would be better use `pin`: `\path [name intersections={of=A--C and B--D,by={[pin=85:$P$]P}}];`